# Combine two SELECT queries together by using value from SELECT in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union, where-clause

```
id | number
---|--------
1  | null
2  | 1
3  | null
4  | 0
5  | 4
6  | 4
```

This is what I want to do this in **one** query. How can I combine both of these queries together?

```
$id = 4;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id OR number = $id

// This will return rows 4,5,6
```

2nd query:

```
$id = 5;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id AND id = $numberColumnOfId AND number = $numberOfColumnId;

// This will return rows 4,5,6
```

`$numberColumnOfId` is the `number` of the `$id`. So if the `$id = 5`, then the `number` would be 4. So select rows where ID = 5.

How can I combine both of the SELECT statements together?

Comment: Mmm, this is quite unclear. Given your current input data, would you please show us what result you would expect for a few different input `$id = 4` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries that you combine with `UNION`.

The first query gets the rows with the given $id`, the second query gets the ones that match via the`number` column.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = $id OR number = $id
UNION
SELECT u1.*
FROM users AS u1
JOIN users AS u2 ON u1.number = u2.number OR u1.id = u2.number
WHERE u2.id = $id or u2.number = $id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x5NMtQA1br6L2UPhxKSTYW/0)